# How do I check convergence of this improper integral?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

This is the improper integral:
$$\int_0^{2} \frac{\ln(1+x^{\frac{3}{5}})}{e^{\sin{x}}-1}dx$$

I tried to compare with $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ but the limit is $0$ and improper integral of $\frac{1}{\sin x}$  is divergent and I can't' say anything about my integral.

Comment: I can compare to x^(3/5)/sinx and limit is 1 but how do I check the convergence of x^(3/5)/sinx integral?

Answer (score 1):

Near $0$, you have
$$\frac{\ln(1+ \sqrt[5]{x^3})}{e^{\sin(x)}-1} = \frac{\sqrt[5]{x^3} + o\left(\sqrt[5]{x^3} \right)}{x + o(x)} \sim x^{-2/5} $$

so by comparison, your integral converges.

Comment: How did you get the first part of the equation?

Comment: Expanding the function near $0$ :)